# how to unit test a global function i.e. $rootScope.functionname in angularJs

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I've a basic controller and inside I've a global function that is called from a different controller, which works absolutely fine in a running application.

Now does anybody know how to unit test this global function?

### the cntrl it contains the function

```
apmstore.controller('HeaderCtrl', function(authentication, $rootScope, $scope, loginService){

 // how to test this function called in the loginCtrl below
 $rootScope.setDropDownStatus = function(visID, user, userImg) {
        $scope.dropdown = visID;
        $scope.user = user; 
        $scope.imgUrl = userImg;
   };
 });
```

### loginCtrl

```
apmstore.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, authentication, loginService,
    $rootScope) {
authentication.isAuthenticated = false;

//Here is where its called, i want to unit test this    
$rootScope.setDropDownStatus(false, null, null);

$scope.templates = [ {url : '/login'}, {url : '/config'} ];
$scope.login = function() {
    loginService.login($scope);
}
});
```

Do I need to change the logic in `HeaderCtrl` to make it easier to test, i.e. decouple into a service/factory etc?

Anyone know how to tackle this? Thanks

Comment: Is this function used somewhere else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
it('should call setDropDownStatus ', inject(function($rootScope, $controller, authentication, loginService) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();

   //fake the setDropDownStatus function as we don't care where this function is created 
   //We only care about whether this function is called.
    $rootScope.setDropDownStatus = function(){

    }
    spyOn($rootScope, "setDropDownStatus");
    ////////

    ctrl = $controller('loginCtrl', {
      $scope: $scope,
      authentication: authentication,
      loginService: loginService,
      $rootScope: $rootScope
    });

    //verify that this function is called with expected parameters.
    expect($rootScope.setDropDownStatus).toHaveBeenCalledWith(false,null,null);

  }));
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/pVtCt2oBAjDGj5TMLAH4?p=preview)

Comment: Does this really unit test the function? It is just checking that a fake version of it was called. It is not even a good test that the function has been called because it defines the function on `$rootScope` prior to instantiating `loginCtrl`. The most likely point of failure (and partly why the function should go in a service) is the function may not have been defined before it is used. Of course we can ensure it is defined prior, but that is a fragile solution.

Comment: @david004:`It is just checking that a fake version of it was called.` => it's what the OP wants to test. About testing how this function works is another test case.

Comment: @david004: `The most likely point of failure is the function may not have been defined before it is used.`. We should not care about this in unit tests because unit tests should be isolated from each other and from real implementations.

Comment: You are correct if the SUT is `loginCtrl`, which is responsible for calling `setDropDownStatus`. But that is not the question.

Comment: @david004: This is what I see in the question's comment: `Here is where its called, i want to unit test this`. Do you think that the OP wants to check whether the function is called?

Comment: Yes, I think the OP question is vague enough for you to get away with that. And it's been accepted, so you must be right. But would you agree the SUT in your test is `loginCtrl`? And would you agree that the function should go into a service?

Comment: @david004: yes, the SUT in my test is `loginCtrl`. About whether the function should go to a service depends on the context. I'm really not sure about the logic of this application. But from what I can see, this function still has access to scope variables (`dropdown`, `user`, `imgUrl`), how can we make this a service function? It would make more sense if the `setDropDownStatus` access $rootScope instead of $scope, though. And we should initialize the $rootScope in `.run` instead of `HeaderCtrl`

Answer (score 0):

Yes to your last question. You shouldn't be defining a function in one controller and using it in another. Put it in a service and inject the service wherever needed.

Comment: Do you know how to decouple it into a service?